# Creating a foreach array from multiple xml elements

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I have been trying to create a `foreach` loop that will get every `ListingId` from the XML file but for some reason I can only get one 'Id'

**XML STRUCTURE:**

```
<List>
    <Listing>
        <ListingId></ListingId>
</Listing>
    <Listing>
        <ListingId></ListingId>
</Listing>
    <Listing>
        <ListingId></ListingId>
</Listing>
</List>
```

**PHP:**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("domain.co.nz/xml.xml");

        foreach($xml->List->Listing->ListingId as $value)
        {

            $xmlArray[] = $value;
        }
```

Comment: I assume you're using SimpleXML from your incomplete code. It would be worth including those lines as well. Also, despite the name, `SimpleXML` ends up being less simple than `DOM` for any non-trivial XML processing. You'll be much better served to learn how to use `DOM` instead.

Comment: try list: foreach($xml->List), if $value is tree object, you are on way to parse it, but you'll need to have other nested forcycles. Not sure if is it best way. But good to imagine.

Comment: @rdlowrey I have included my one and only SimpleXML line of code

Comment: @JirkaKopřiva List showed all the data but then I still have to go Listing to get the id and I am still getting one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$xml = '<List>
    <Listing>
        <ListingId>12</ListingId>
</Listing>
    <Listing>
        <ListingId>13</ListingId>
</Listing>
    <Listing>
        <ListingId>14</ListingId>
</Listing>
</List>';


$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$arr = array();

foreach($xml->Listing as $value)
{
    $arr[] = intval($value->ListingId);
}

print_r($arr); //Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 13 [2] => 14 )
```

Comment: David how could  I do that from an external document

Comment: Exactly like you did. This was just a convenience move for me to be able to test this without creating an xml file. Just stick to `$xml = simplexml_load_file("domain.co.nz/xml.xml");` which is doing exactly the same, but from a file.

Comment: Thanks David,  I have copied and your code and all I am getting is an `Array ( )`

Comment: Changed the foreach to `List->Listing->`